# I can't upgrade Debian 9

Tags: debian, upgrade

I execute: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and I get this:

```
Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Calculation of the update ... Some packages can not be installed. This may mean
That you have asked for the impossible, or if you
Unstable distribution, which some packages have not yet
Have been created or have not been released from Incoming.
The following information should help you resolve the situation:

The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
  Systemd: Break: rdnssd (<1.0.1-5) but 1.0.1-1 + b1 must be installed
E: Error, pkgProblem :: Resolve generated breaks, which could be caused by the packages to be kept as is.
```

OUTPUT `apt-cache policy rdnssd`

```
   Dmicaelandre @ ThinkPad: ~ $ apt-cache policy rdnssd
rdnssd:
  Installed: 1.0.1-1+b1
  Candidate: 1.0.3-3
  Version table:
      1.0.3-3 0
         650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main amd64 Packages
  *** 1.0.1-1+b1 0
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

OUTPUT `apt-cache policy`

```
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/contrib Translation-en
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 650 http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main Translation-fr
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/contrib Translation-en
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
 650 http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp2.fr.debian.org
```

Comment: Please run `sudo LANG=C apt-get dist-upgrade` and paste the output instead of manually translating.

Comment: Additionally, please [edit] your question to show the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy rdnssd`.

Comment: There seems to be a bug report about Network Manager and rdnssd not working together https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740998      This thread suggests that rdnssd can be removed http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=129613&start=30

Answer (score 1):

As implied by [arochester's comment](/questions/349347/i-cant-upgrade-debian-9#comment618293_349347), remove that `rdnssd` package.

```
sudo apt-get remove rdnssd
```

This has allowed me to go on upgrading to Debian 9.

This package is a kind of auto-conf daemon for dns. On my system, it was just regularly breaking havoc on my dns settings by overriding settings from networkmanager. (I have understood that this was this same package which was causing me those DNS troubles when searching information on it, for knowing how to solve the upgrade trouble.)
If you do not know this `rdnssd` package nor what is "DNS configuration using the Recursive DNS Server (RDNSS) option", it is likely you actually do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Recommended upgrade procedure is to:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get upgrade
3. apt-get dist-upgrade

Doing a regular upgrade first fixed it for me.